# getChildHtml('content') in magento?

Tags: magento

Anybody please help me

I can't find `getChildHtml('content')` 
I'm new in magento?

Where is `getChildHtml('content')` in **magento**?

Comment: for reference : http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

see

```
<reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav1" template="catalog/navigation/left_nav.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

writing the above code will display all the contents in left_nav.phtml(php+html[view part]) in the content part of that page.
Mainly there are :

```
<reference name="left">--->display in left side of page
<reference name="right">--->display in right side of page
<reference name="head">--->display in head side of page 
<reference name="content">--->display in middle of page
```

`getChildHtml('content')`--->will display all page declared under `<reference name="content">` in the middle part of the called layout page.

This is a slight overview of your doubt.Make an effort to learn from googling.
Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

You may get childhtml('content') in every layout.phtml files like 1column.phtml and other in app/rwd/default/page